# Eclipse: fully remove an old project?

Tags: eclipse, project

I run eclipse on Ubuntu 11.10. I originally created a project in folder **foo**. I subsequently deleted that project to re-organise folders and I now want to create a new project in folder **foo/bar** but Eclipse won't let me because it says the the new directory is a sub-directory of an existing project.

How can I force Eclipse to forget about the original project so that I can create the new one?

Comment: I still have issues with this and it is driving me mad. Every time I delete a project (and all of its content), eclipse remembers there used to be a project in that directory and prevents me from re-using that location. I just cannot find any config file that stores that information.

Comment: I tried this:
find $HOME -name ".project" -print

And this:
find $HOME -type f | while read f; do grep -H -n projectname "$f"; done

And checked this location too:
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects

But still no luck.

Answer (score 49):

In general, the deleting the project from the ***"/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects"*** should work, but if you're using 'working sets', you might have the problem I had once, which is basically have a 'ghost' project in your workspace that you can't delete because it says "this project doesn't exist anymore".

If this is your problem, try to delete an entry for your 'ghost project' in the file:

***"/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml"***  (on MacOS).

Comment: The /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml solution worked great for me.

Comment: tfw you find this answer after a long time and cannot upvote again :-)

Comment: Awesome........I spent 1 day on this BS problem...Literally, you saved me man..!!!!!!!!!! Big Hug...

Comment: I had a similar issue with a 'ghost' project but it didn't have an entry for the project in org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml. What fixed it for me was make an entry for the project in workingsets.xml (with Eclipse closed). After that I restarted Eclipse and the project showed up in the package explorer where I could delete it again.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the project from /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects and not the whole .metadata folder will save all other projects and config.

Comment: In my case, deleting .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects did not help.

Answer (score 4):

I have also encountered this problem, except it's been in Windows.  I didn't want to completely remove the .metadata folder and none of the other solutions fixed it.

I managed to fix it by removing the file `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.safetable\org.eclipse.core.resources` while Eclipse was closed.  The file gets saved when closing Eclipse so I guess it is cached while Eclipse is open.

Comment: that ruined my workspace completely and I had to set it up from the start again, make sure to keep a copy of `.safetale\org.eclipse.core.resources` if you want to try this

Comment: This worked in a Docker container that I've built a Python dev environment in; although it did have the side-effect of removing all projects from the explorer. But, no other solutions worked for me, so I just went to `file>open projects from file system` and added everything back. The `org.core.resources` file was regenerated and all is well.

Comment: Same here - Lost my entire workspace. I should have known better than to just blow the file away rather than taking a look first.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your workspace folder using some file manager (you can find your workspace location, be clicking **File -> Swich Workspace...**) and delete your foo folder, or simple remove its contents (*.project* file being most important). Then you should be able to create your new project.

Comment: Well, I went to my workspace and did: rm -rf foo but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to fix it by deleting the workspace/.metadata directory. This resolves the problem but has the side effect of making eclipse forget everything about the workspace so I'm not sure it's a recommended way of fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am running Eclipse Kepler on OS X Mountain Lion, and I had a similar problem. I deleted a project and tried to recreate it in the same location. Eclipse gave me an error saying that the project already existed. I discovered that if I close Eclipse after deleting a project, then reopen it, Eclipse finally 'forgets' the deleted project and allows me to re-create it.

(This question was posted over 1.5 years ago, and I'm guessing that Bruno already tried this and it didn't work. I just want to let others know that this solution worked for me now on Kepler.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with Egit and repositories that I deleted and imported back again, instead of importing as general project choose import as existing project.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try to delete the folders:
 "/your_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources"
"/your_workspace/ProjectName"

Answer (score 1):

If the Project was in a `working set` before you deleted it, you might have to manually remove it from the set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting any file, **rename** it, so if whatever you try doesn't work, you can revert.