# deleting 32 bit SWT and deploying 64 bit one

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

[image: This is the screenshot of eclipse in which when i try to import i am unable to click at the option]
I have read almost all documents pertaining to this topic and i haven't found the precise and correct answer.
I followed this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php)
The exact problem i facing is that i have followed this document and installed a 32 bit SWT. Now when i ran my program i came to know that i should have used 64 bit SWT with 64 bit JVM from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291815/eclipse-cannot-load-32-bit-swt-libraries-on-64-bit-jvm). I downloaded a 64bit version following the link in one of the answer. but when i tried and repeated the process of importing it says i already have a project. Now i am not able to put that 64bit SWT in my project. 
Can anyone help me out with this.
Please keep in my mind i am new to JAVA and this is the first time i am using Eclipse RCP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045609/eclipse-fully-remove-an-old-project) 
Actually i went to the workspace location manually deleted the project and voila i was able to import again. and the program ran. Thanks for your suggestions